# jshint and Function() gets: Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor

Tags: javascript, jshint

I want to use a "noop" function (I mean, a function that doesn't do nothing, just for mockup purposes). So I write:

```
var noop = Function();
```

But when I run **jshint** over the file, Im getting the following error:

```
Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
```

This error goes away when I change `Function()` for `Function.prototype`, but I prefer the first one.

Why this error happens? How can I prevent this hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any function with the first character as upper case when invoked is considered to be a new instance. you can just do var noop = function(){} which will give you the same result. Plus, it is considered a bad practice to use Function() directly.

Comment: why is it a bad practice?

Comment: functions created by Function() is parsed when it is invoked. This is less efficient than using function(){} expression which is parsed with the rest of the code. Functions created with Function() is created at the global scope, always. Don't get me wrong, it has it's place. It is considered a better practice to use Function() instead of eval. That is one place when I would use it. In most situations used named functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression actually is the same as

```
var noop = new Function();
```

or

```
var noop = new Function;
```

you can see that it creates a new object each time by running `Function() === Function()`

The shortest and safest alternative I saw to be used in production was:

```
var noop = Number;
```

jshint should be cool with this one. An advantage is that it does not create a new object each time it is used.

*Update:*
just for the sake of completeness, jshint complains because invoking constructors (capitalized first letter means a constructor by convention) without new can be dangerous, because `this` in those functions is `window` in ES3 and any changes to `this` modifies global object.